# PDO Multiple Execution Issues

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two inserts on a processing page. The first works without a hitch. The second will not even activate. I even tried putting a PDO query to see if it would work but still nothing.

```
        $cpinsert = $db->prepare('insert into Chatposts values (0, :chatid, :name, :url, :text, now(), :ipaddress, 0)');

        $cpinsert -> bindParam(':chatid', $chatroomid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $cpinsert -> bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $cpinsert -> bindParam(':url', $url, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $cpinsert -> bindParam(':text', $text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $cpinsert -> bindParam(':ipaddress', $ipaddress, PDO::PARAM_STR);


            $cpinsert -> execute();

        // Needs an error checker
        $cpid = $cpinsert ->lastInsertID();
        $cpinsert->closeCursor();
```

^ That works fine, though I don't know about the lastinsertid since I cannot test it.

\V/ Nothing in there will execute no matter what I try. Something is preventing anything there from executing or I didn't close the above's connection properly.

```
    // Targets Insert
    //if (isset($target)):
    $query = "insert into Targets values (9,'rommel')";
    $db->query($query);
        $targetinsert = $db->prepare('insert into Targets values (:cpid,:tname)');


        foreach ($target as $tname):
            $targetinsert -> bindParam(':cpid', $cpid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $targetinsert -> bindParam(':tname', $tname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        endforeach; 


            $targetinsert -> execute();

    //endif;
```

I have tried everything I know of and no luck. It is quite possible I did a minor mistake since I am new to PDO. Closecursor didn't seem to do anything either when I added it in.

Comment: Make sure your PDO is configured to [throw exceptions on errors](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php#example-978), so you can see what goes wrong. Then think about what you're doing. You're only calling `execute` once, so *at best* it will execute the `INSERT INTO Targets VALUES(..)` once and insert a single row.

Comment: It is. The problem is this is on a processing page that attempts to kick you off in so many ways that seeing the error is a challenge in itself. I was hoping it would be a simple coding error that can be seen visually. Yes I am aware of the execute issue, I was working on it while I tested to see if it even worked the first time and it didn't.

Comment: So the problem is really that you don't know how to debug your code? Install [xDebug](http://xdebug.org/index.php) and step through your code line by line.

Comment: The only way I know how to debug right now is error messages, if's checking variables/results, and commenting out lines of code =/. If there is a better way of doing it I'll jump at it. I'll have to check that out tommor- later  today, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You said you need to do execute many inserts, but for some reason you are executing your query only **once**.

Also, please remove these try..catch things from your code - they are **the** reason why you have no idea what's going wrong

Comment: I cannot get it to execute even once so I will worry about repetition once it will submit a query. I've been seeing a lot of code on stackoverflow with try catches around the execute, is there a better way? Also removed try-catch blocks in code and still nothing being submitted.

Answer (score -2):

I had to recreate a half functional model of my page but I found the problem, it was lastinsertid(). I was applying a PDOstatement class on a PDO class.

Before:

```
 $cpid = $cpinsert->lastInsertID();
```

After:

```
 $cpid = $db->lastInsertID();
```

I just had to call the Database instead of the prepare with that line of code.